# How to display associated simple products with custom options in the grouped product in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, custom-options, grouped-products

I am using Magento 2.3.0

I have grouped products on my website. I have displayed all associated simple product with their tier prices, product names and quantity. please refer below screenshot. For e.x. let's take "Test product 1" from below screenshot. I have added custom options with the input type checkbox and added $0.20 price in that custom option. Now I want to display this custom option with checkbox in the column "Price Tag - $0.20". so, when customer check checkbox for any product then it will add an additional $0.20 price for that particular product into the cart. How can I do this?

Note: Remember all prices in screenshots are tier prices and column names are quantity range

[image]